# How to select elements when there is a space in an HTML class

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, web-scraping, nokogiri

How do I use CSS selectors to get the "This is the text I need" line below?

I don't know how to deal with spaces in the table class.

```
<table class="some name">
<thead> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">50</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="/thing" title="thing">This is the text I need</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are spaces in the class attribute value, that means there are multiple classes applied to the element. To locate an element with multiple classes, the `css` selector is just a chain of the classes. Generally, the form looks like:

```
element.class1.class2
```

Therefore, assuming the link is the first in the table with class "some" and "name", you can do:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = %Q{
<table class="some name">
    <thead> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;">50</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="/thing" title="thing">This is the text I need</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
}

doc = Nokogiri::XML(html)

# Assuming you need both classes to uniquely identify the table
p doc.at_css('table.some.name a').text
#=> "This is the text I need"

# Note that you do not need to use both classes if one of them is unique
p doc.at_css('table.name a').text
#=> "This is the text I need"
```